# whats the reason for the "could not find or load main class "error?

Tags: java

more explanation:while writing the regular "HELLO WORD" code I always face this error-noticing that the compilation goes without any errors(I mean this error appear when running) & that I use TEXTPAD for writing java programs

The code is

```
class HelloWorld 
{ 
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println(“Hello World!”); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Post the package where the class file is generated and how you run the program i.e. the command line.

Comment: Please, considering pasting a code that serve as example of your problem, we are smart people but cannot dig into your brain by the internet, neither in person if you are thinking...

Comment: have you put your main method in the same class where you're running?

Comment: `class HelloWorld {
public static void main (String args[]) {
System.out.println(“Hello World!”);
}
}`

Comment: and the fileis named HelloWorld.java ?

Comment: yes this is the file name

Comment: and how do you compile them? javac HelloWorld.java and then java HelloWorld ? take into consideration capital letters

Comment: if you're running it from the command line, make sure you're running the `.class` file and not the `.java` file

Comment: I compile them by going to tools then external tools then compile java I said yhat I use the textpad!

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with your code.  The error is likely due to the way you are launching the program.  This is why people are asking all the questions in the comments.  You should provide a more complete example so your error is reproducible.

Comment: thks alot I solved that problem

Answer (score 1):

HelloWorld from scratch:

1. Create a folder to do the hello world code

> ```
> cd ~
> mkdir test
> cd test
> ```

1. Create and edit the HelloWorld file

> ```
> gedit HelloWorld.java
> ```

code:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

1. Save and compile, take care of capital letters.

> ```
> javac HelloWorld.java
> ```

1. Execute

> java HelloWorld

output:

> Hello world!